# How to set a minimum view count for a video search on YouTube? Is there any parameter for minimum view count in the search URL?

Tags: youtube

I want to search YouTube for some keyword/s and sort them based on rating. But some recently added videos with 100% rating (with just one or two likes and no dislikes) hog the top of the list thereby denying me any useful result.

Is there any way to limit the search to videos that have a view count more than a particular value? Preferably is there any parameter (say `minViewCount` or something) that I can add to the search URL to get the result?

(I have seen this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331795/find-videos-with-a-minimum-number-of-views-with-youtube-api, but this only helps developers.)